# How to add a callback function to an existing JavaScript function without adding code to the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Let say I have `foo()`. Is there a way to execute `bar()` after `foo()` without modifying `foo()`?

```
foo(){ /* logic */}

bar(){ /* more logic *}

afterEvent1AlwaysExecute2(foo,bar);
```

Any non-jQuery or jQuery comments are appreciated :)

Comment: You could always wrap `foo` inside a new function which will call the old `foo`, and then call `bar`. Then you change the name of this new function to `foo`. As far as the outside world is concerned `foo` should work as expected, but secretly your replaced implementation will also call `bar`. Win!

Answer (score 9):

You can do it without adding code to `foo`, by reassigning the name `foo`:

```
var original_foo = foo;
var foo = function() { original_foo(); bar(); }
```